# Get checked items from a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm just getting used to MVVM and want to do without the code-behind and define everything in the view-models.
the combobox represents several selection options (works). I would like to query the elements that have been checked.
Unfortunately I can't access them. The textbox should display all selected elements as concatenated string.

**View-Model**

```
class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        #region Fields

        private ObservableCollection<EssayTypeViewModel> _essayTypes;
        private EssayTypeViewModel _selectedEssayTypes;

        #endregion


        public ObservableCollection<EssayTypeViewModel> EssayTypes
        {
            get => _essayTypes;
            set
            {
                if (_essayTypes == value) return;
                _essayTypes = value; OnPropertyChanged("EssayTypes");
            }
        }


        public EssayTypeViewModel SelectedEssayTypes
        {
            get => _selectedEssayTypes;
            set { _selectedEssayTypes = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEssayTypes"); }
        }


        public MainViewModel()
        {

            // Load Essay Types
            EssayTypeRepository essayTypeRepository = new EssayTypeRepository();
            var essayTypes = essayTypeRepository.GetEssayTypes();
            var essayTypeViewModels = essayTypes.Select(m => new EssayTypeViewModel()
            {
                Text = m.Text
            });

            EssayTypes = new ObservableCollection<EssayTypeViewModel>(essayTypeViewModels);

        }
    }
```

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="Listitems" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="75" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding EssayTypes}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Text}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedEssayTypes}" Grid.Column="0" Width="160" Height="25" Margin="0,140,0,0"/>
```

Comment: *"The textbox should display all selected elements as concatenated string"* - the hardest part is to notify `TextBox` when it has to re-evalute binding. `SelectedEssayTypes` could be a simple getter-only property, which join `EssayTypes.Where(o => o.Checked)`. If you create items in code behind, then consider passing main window view model instance inside (e.g. as constructor parameter), then each item can rise notification in `Checked` setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hook up an event handler to the `PropertyChanged` event of all `EssayTypeViewModel` objects in the `EssayTypes` collection and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for a read-only property of the `MainViewModel` that returns all selected elements as concatenated string:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    // Load Essay Types
    EssayTypeRepository essayTypeRepository = new EssayTypeRepository();
    var essayTypes = essayTypeRepository.GetEssayTypes();
    var essayTypeViewModels = essayTypes.Select(m =>
    {
        var vm = EssayTypeViewModel()
        {
            Text = m.Text
        };
        vm.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
        return vm;
    });

    EssayTypes = new ObservableCollection<EssayTypeViewModel>(essayTypeViewModels);
}

private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Checked")
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItems");
}

public string SelectedItems => string.Join(",", EssayTypes.Where(x => x.Checked).ToArray());
```

This requires the EssayTypeViewModel class to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (by for example deriving from your `BaseViewModel` class).

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Mode = Two way on the checkbox binding.

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Text}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

then you can iterate through the essay types collection to check if the item entry was checked.

For ex.  Sample code can be:

```
foreach (var essayTypeInstance in EssayTypes)
{
     if(essayTypeInstance.Checked)
     {
          // this value is selected
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was fast! But how does the Property know that an item was checked? Using code behind, I bound the combobox to an event and casted the sender to retrieve all checked values. But without any code behind I do not know how to to announce that something has changed.

Comment: That will automatically happen because of two way binding.

Answer (score 0):

mm8 answer works. In the meantime i came up with another approach. Not 100% MVVM compatible but it works and is quite simple.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListItems" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="75" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfItems}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay}" Unchecked="GetCheckedElements" Checked="GetCheckedElements" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItemsString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="0" Width="160" Height="25" Margin="0,140,0,0"/>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }


        private void GetCheckedElements(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (DataContext as MainViewModel)?.FindCheckedItems();
            (DataContext as MainViewModel)?.ConcatSelectedElements();
        }

    }
```

**Model**

```
public class Items
    {
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

**ItemsViewModel** (BaseViewModel only implements INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
class ItemsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private bool _checked;
        private string _name;

        public bool Checked
        {
            get => _checked;
            set
            {
                if (value == _checked) return;

                _checked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Checked");
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                if (value == _name) return;

                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
```

**MainViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string _selectedItemsString;
        private ObservableCollection<Items> _selectedItems;



        public ObservableCollection<Items> CollectionOfItems { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Items> SelectedItems
        {
            get => _selectedItems;
            set
            {
                _selectedItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItems");
            } 
        }


        public string SelectedItemsString
        {
            get => _selectedItemsString;
            set
            {
                if (value == _selectedItemsString) return;

                _selectedItemsString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItemsString");
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            CollectionOfItems = new ObservableCollection<Items>();
            SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<Items>();




            CollectionOfItems.Add(new Items { Checked = false, Name = "Item 1" });
            CollectionOfItems.Add(new Items { Checked = false, Name = "Item 2" });
            CollectionOfItems.Add(new Items { Checked = false, Name = "Item 3" });

        }


        public void FindCheckedItems()
        {
            CollectionOfItems.Where(x => x.Checked).ToList().ForEach(y => SelectedItems.Add(y));
        }


        public void ConcatSelectedElements()
        {
            SelectedItemsString = string.Join(", ", CollectionOfItems.Where(x => x.Checked).ToList().Select(x => x.Name)).Trim();
        }
    }
```